# Hide Folders and Files using command prompt

Tags: command-prompt

I want to hide my folders and files also using command prompt.so, how can i do that ?

i don't want to hide my folders from the properties. so, please guys don't reply your answer like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use bellow comman

```
attrib -r -h -s "Your Folder path"
```